# transparent panel with visibility criteria-Android

Tags: android

I want to create a transparent panel with two buttons , previous and next.

As  i am using two edittext box. if i click on any edit text box that panel become visible and i can move in edittext through previous and next button.

How Can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution of ur problem.I m using here two edit text so that you can understand how with id "layout01" will visible and invisible when we focus to second edit text and remove focus from it(click on second edit text or bring focus there u'll get buttons "Previous" and "Next" at the bottom of the screen.)

XML Code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/layout00"
                    >  

    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/edit0" 
              android:text="first write here"
              android:editable="false"/>

    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/edit1" 
              android:text="after that write here"
              android:editable="false"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/layout01"
                    android:gravity="bottom|center"
                    android:visibility="invisible">

        <TableRow > 

        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/previous"
                android:text="Privious"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:text="Next"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>  

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java Code:-

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

public class Edit extends Activity{

    TableLayout tl;
    EditText et;
    //int flag = 0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit);

        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1);
        tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout01);


       et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(hasFocus){
            tl.setVisibility(1);
               }
                else{
                    tl.setVisibility(8);
                    Log.d("without focus", "it should be here");
                } 
        }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In android, you need to take a layout which contains the two button, e.g., linear layout which is having orientation as horizontal and background as #00000000(indicating for transparent).

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:background="#00000000">
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: through this code only background become transparent, i want when i click on edit box the panel including two buttons become visible after that panel become invisible.